# Создание своей миниSCADA. Шаг первый.

Tags: модемы, c++

Суть вопроса сводится к следующему. Есть N объектов с ПЛК и модемами соответственно. Нужно написать программу, которая бы связывалась с модемами и считывала бы соответствующие регистры данных. Потом эти данные записываем в БД, откуда потом будем считывать их по необходимости (пока этот вопрос не стоит). Использоваться вероятно будут Linux,MySQL, хотя возможно и другое. Хотелось бы получить совет именно по обращению к модему на объекте ПЛК и считыванию данных с него. Какие функции и библиотеки есть, какие-нибудь подобные системы с хорошим и подробным описанием может кто-нибудь посоветует. Язык С++ (возможно С#). Просто это первая программа именно для железа, поэтому с чего начать, откуда двигаться толком не знаю. Заранее спасибо за любой совет и помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Могу подсказать два opensource проекта:

1. [OpenSCADA](http://oscada.org/ru/), вот [репозиторий](http://oscada.org/websvn/listing.php?repname=OpenSCADA)
2. [FreeSCADA](http://www.free-scada.org/)

Думаю, есть смысл такой вопрос на форумах этих проектов задать или посмотреть сам код.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно есть полезная информация.